# vanishing of a certain cyclic permutation sum of tensors

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, connections, symplectic-linear-algebra

I am stuck while reading what appears to be a very basic differential geometric argument about existence of torsion-free symplictic connections from here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0511194.pdf It is at the bottom of the page 1, and is about the following. Let $\nabla^0$ be a torsion-free connection, and $\omega$ a symplectic from on a manifold $M$. Define the tensor $N(X,Y)$ as the one the satisfies
$$
\nabla^0_X \omega(Y,Z) = \omega(N(X,Y),Z)
$$
Then it is claimed that since $\omega$ is closed, the cyclic sum
$$
\omega(N(X,Y),Z)  + \omega(N(Y,Z),X) + \omega(N(Z,X),Y)
$$
vanishes.

Why is this true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the definition of the covariant derivative, the antisymmetry of $\omega$, and $\nabla_{X}Y - \nabla_{Y}X = [X, Y]$ (Lie bracket):
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\omega(N(X, Y), Z) &+ \omega(N(Y, Z), X) + \omega(N(Z, X), Y)\\
& = (\nabla_{X}\omega)(Y, Z) + (\nabla_{Y}\omega)(Z, X) + (\nabla_{Z}\omega)(X, Y)\\
&= X\omega(Y, Z) + Y\Omega(Z, X) + Z \omega(X, Y) \\&\quad- \omega(\nabla_{X}Y, Z) - \omega(Y, \nabla_{X}Z) - \omega(\nabla_{Y}Z, X) - \\
&\qquad \omega(Z, \nabla_{Y}Z) - \omega(\nabla_{Z}X, Y) - \omega(X, \nabla_{Z}Y)\\
& =  X\omega(Y, Z) + Y\Omega(Z, X) + Z \omega(X, Y)\\
&\quad - \omega(\nabla_{X}Y- \nabla_{Y}X, Z)  - \omega(\nabla_{Y}Z - \nabla_{Z}Y, X)  - \omega(\nabla_{Z}X - \nabla_{X}Z, Y)\\
& = X\omega(Y, Z) + Y\Omega(Z, X) + Z \omega(X, Y) \\
&\quad - \omega([X, Y], Z)  - 
\omega([Y, Z], X) - \omega([Z, X], Y)\\
& = d\omega(X, Y, Z).
\end{split}
\end{align}

Comment: Beat me to it—I was working out the details. But you should fix some typos ($\Omega$, $\nabla YZ$). Perhaps also make it clear that you're using the fact that $\nabla_X$ is a derivation to get $X\big(\omega(Y,Z)\big) = \nabla_X\omega(Y,Z) + \omega(\nabla_XY,Z) + \omega(Y,\nabla_XZ)$.

Comment: how do you get the very last equality?

Comment: I assume that's some consequence of Cartan's formula but I have never seen it written down in this form. How do you derive it?

Comment: [I know Cartan's formula as $d i_X + i_X d=L_X$ where $L_X$ is the Lie derivative, and $i_X$ is contraction with $X$.]

Comment: No, it's not Cartan's formula. It's the formula for the exterior derivative generalizing $$d\phi(X,Y) = X\phi(Y)-Y\phi(X)-\phi([X,Y])$$ for $1$-forms $\phi$. You can find it in most textbooks.

Comment: @DimaSustretov: The last formula is the definition of the exterior derivative.

Comment: @DanFox: Well, it's certainly not a definition I've ever given in a course or used myself. :P Did Robert really give that as a definition?!

Comment: @TedShifrin: If you think of smooth differential forms as a module over the Lie algebra of smooth vector fields, the usual Lie algebra coboundary gives the exterior derivative in the form I have used. One can check that this agrees with the coordinate definition. Modulo different conventions regarding constant factors, this is done in Proposition 3.11 in volume 1 of Kobayashi and Nomizu. By the way, I have no idea what Robert you are talking about.

Comment: My previous comment should say view "smooth functions" rather than "smooth differential forms" as a module over the Lie algebra of vector fields.